# Using XPath to get Webpage Data

Tags: python, xml, xpath

I'm trying to write a program that goes through an HTML page and gets the data one the page.  My question comes when using XPath.  The webpage has a layout like this:

```
<div class="left">
    <div class="name">
    </div>
</div>
<div class="right">
    <div class="name">
    </div>
</div>
```

I'm trying to separate each name class using xpath but when I use:

```
tree.xpath('//div[@class="name"]/text()')
```

I get everything on the page that uses the class **name**.  How would I go about making the xpath more specific?

So far I have tried the following:

```
tree.xpath('//div[class="left"]/div[@class="name"]/text()')
```

but that doesn't work and returns an empty array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> `//div[class="left"]/div[@class="name"]/text()`

It is almost correct, you are just missing the `@` before the `class`:

```
//div[@class="left"]/div[@class="name"]/text()
  HERE^
```